# Java webapp - where to put application-generated files?

Tags: java, file, web-applications, neo4j

I'm working on a Java web application that needs to store uploaded files in one directory, and an embedded Neo4j database in another directory.  I'm deploying the warfile to Tomcat to serve the application, and the application needs to be runnable under Tomcat in either Linux or Windows.

**Where exactly should I be putting these two directories on the host system's filesystem?**

I'm confused since I'm accustomed to storing information in databases specified via a URL, etc.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I eventually ended up having the application create a directory for itself under /var/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a chance webapp have two or more instances running at the same time, say in a same Tomcat with two /path names?

Java has system property *user.home* you could always create a subfolder on it. Current user is the one running Tomcat server. Print properties to sysout for debug purpose.

Reading a webapp name at runtime you can use servletContext.getRealPath("/") function. You get a filename path to $tomcat/webapps/mywebapp and use last folder entry. Define ServletContextListener in web.xml so you can read webapp name at startup.

Use naming convention *${user.home}/tomcat/${webappname}/* and store any file you please.

Or define a webapp context-param variable in web.xml file and let deployer create an appropriate folder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29